# Copy of a trigger does not work

Tags: mysql

I created a separate test database by taking production and using mysqldump on it. When I recreated the triggers by copying and pasting the code they fail to work on the test database. TOAD throws 'CREATED_DATE does not have a default value' error. So I went back to production and tested the triggers and it worked as expected. The goal of the trigger is to set the default value of a date field, there are 2 total and it is a variant of what you see.

FROM PRODUCTION

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` TRIGGER `iwebprod`.`CREATED_DATE` BEFORE INSERT ON iwebprod.library_record FOR EACH ROW
    SET NEW.CREATED_DATE = IFNULL(NEW.CREATED_DATE, NOW());
```

FROM TEST

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` TRIGGER `iwebprod`.`CREATED_DATE` BEFORE INSERT ON iwebprod.library_record FOR EACH ROW
    SET NEW.CREATED_DATE = IFNULL(NEW.CREATED_DATE, NOW());
```

THE DML IN QUESTION

```
INSERT INTO LIBRARY_RECORD(LIBRARY_RECORD_ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION, SOURCE, ATTACHMENT_ONLY, CONTENT_TYPE_ID, INTRANET_DISPLAY,
              INTERNET_DISPLAY, ACTIVE_DATE, ARCHIVE_DATE)
VALUES ('5895', 'moowcow', 'rbgsb', 'library/oracle2mysql.exe', '0', '23', '1', '0', '30-Jan-2013', '31-Jan-2013')
```

I use TOAD for MySQL and if anyone can explain why this is happening or somehow notice something different about the code I would appreciate it.

Comment: As an aside, perhaps you simply want the [automatic initialisation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/timestamp-initialization.html) properties of MySQL's `TIMESTAMP` datatype?

Comment: That would be ideal but unfortunately I read that you can only use one timestamp field that has a default. Unless I interpreted it incorrectly.

Comment: Only one `TIMESTAMP` column can automatically initialise to the current time, but other `TIMESTAMP` columns can have constant default values.

Comment: Bah I figured it out, I forgot to modify the table definitions for this trigger setup to work.

Answer (score 0):

That could be because you **didn't** set `NULL = YES` for  `CREATED_DATE` (declare that `CREATED_DATE` may be `null`) in `LIBRARY_RECORD` table

but when you **insert** `LIBRARY_RECORD`, you didn't insert the `CREATED_DATE`

you should **insert** `CREATED_DATE` 
or allow `CREATED_DATE` to have `NULL` value.